# x64 ymm/SIMD/vector instructions where ymm register is specified in a register?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, simd

Do any SIMD/vector register instructions exist where the ymm register is specified in a general register (or SIMD register) rather than in the instruction itself?

Essentially what I'm trying to do is write a function that saves any series of consecutive ymm registers onto the local frame.  Here is the idea, except I'm inventing what I consider semi-plausible fictional syntax for the instruction I'm looking for.

```
.text
.align 64
funcname:
    orq         %rcx, %rcx                # is register count <= 0 ???
    jle         funcdone                  # # of registers to save is <= 0

    xorq        %rax, %rax                # rax = 0 == vector save element #

funcloop:
    vmovapd     %ymm(%rsi), (%rdi, %rax)  # save ymm?? to address rdi + rax
    addq        $32, %rax                 # each ymm vector is 32-bytes
    loop        funcloop                  # --rcx; if (rcx > 0) { goto funcloop }

funcdone:
    ret
```

The `vmovapd` instruction is the strange instruction that does what I'm looking for.  I'm sure I've never seen an instruction that looks like that, but that doesn't mean there isn't some unusual instruction that does what I need to do.

Or maybe the instruction would look like one of these:

```
    vmovapd     %rsi, (%rdi, %rax)
    vmovapd     (%rsi), (%rdi, %rax)
```

Another alternative would be bits 0 to 15 in `%rsi` correspond to vector registers `ymm00` to `ymm15`, and the register corresponding to the lowest set bit is saved (or all "set bit" ymm registers get saved).

BTW, for what I need to accomplish, self-modifying code is not an option.

Comment: You can't do that. You could use a jump table (or just a whole bunch of branches) and make it happen, but it will suck. Maybe if you explain what this is actually for (on a higher level than "save a range of ymm regs") I/others can come up with some other ideas

Comment: @harold:  Given what this is for, I'm sure explaining myself would get me brutally pummeled for asking blatantly inappropriate questions!  Been there, done that before. Some folks here are much too sensitive about the rules for my tastes.  But yes, absent some brilliant idea, a jump table will be necessary.

Comment: You could do address arithmetic (and use some fillers to make it work out) to skip the table, that isn't much (if any) better though.

Comment: @harold:  I guess you're just saying "measure how many bytes to implement each save", then fiddle the call address appropriately (rather than have an array of addresses).  If so, I suspect the jump table is more efficient.  But I see where you're going... essentially make the code segments fit into a code array of sorts, with each chunk of code the same length as all others.  That's pretty gross, but this must be balls-to-the-wall fast-as-possible, so... I'll look into that too.  PS:  For new 64-bit ABI to support "smart function protocol" for 32 * 512-bit zmm registers.  Ignore this!  :-)

Comment: @honestann are you by change coming from ARM ? The assembly on ARM (and before that, m68k) has always known "multi-register store/load" operations - i.e. the ability to load/store an arbitrary subset of general-purpose or vector registers in a single instruction. Alas, that's not something Intel has ever implemented in their architecture ...

Comment: @FrankH: No, but looks like I may work with ARM for the first time ever in the coming year, due to the availability of the AMD "seattle", which is 64-bit ARM based.  There really should be instructions that takes a 32/64-bit bitmask value plus a 64-byte aligned address and save/restore the ymm/zmm registers specified by the set bits in the bitmask.  That would make what I am considering very practical.  Without something like this, I suspect the great improvement I was envisioning for the new ABI to support the 32 * 512-bit zmm registers may be very efficient, but too messy to adopt.

Comment: @honestann regarding the 512bit registers ... what Intel has done for `VGATHER` is the ability to do _masked loads_ to (a subset of the constituent 'words' of) one `zmm` reg. I.e. you can express something like "in `zmm0`, load `words[]` from addr `aX[]` i.e. supply an array of pointer offsets, to load/store each constituent of the vector from/to a different address (`_mm512_*gather_*()` / `_mm512_scatter*_*()` intrinsics). What still not exists is the ability to _load multiple regs_ with a single instructions.

Answer (score 2):

x86's state-save instructions (`xsave`/`xrstor`) *do* take masks in `edx:eax` to control what state to save/restore.  It's really complicated, and the insn ref manual just points you at a whole separate section of another manual.  IDK if you get to choose at the level of individual vector registers, though.  More likely there's a single bit for "the low128 of all 16 vector regs", but ymm0-7 are separate from the rest, to avoid saving/restoring ymm8-15 when 32bit code can't affect them.

> The specific state components saved correspond to the bits set in the
>   requested-feature bitmap (RFBM), which is the logical-AND of EDX:EAX
>   and XCR0.

For saving/restoring a few ymm regs in a function prologue/epilogue, it's unlikely to be useful.  I haven't looked into it.  `xsavec` does "compaction": The CPU tracks which pieces of state are actually modified.

There are no other instructions with an extra level of indirection for registers (a register specifies which register).  That would be a big complication for the out-of-order machinery to implement.  Even ARM load-multiple instructions (see the other answer) have the register bitmask embedded into the instruction, so it's available as the instruction is being decoded (rather than being filled in later).

---

You're probably better off with the obvious store/reload of any vector register you want to use, but that are call-preserved in the calling convention you're designing.

Note that future extensions to wider vectors mean you will end up with only the low 256b of your chosen vector regs being call-preserved, with the bits above that being clobbered.  (zeroed or not, when callees don't touch them, instead of saving/restoring).

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to "SIMD load / store", there's two different approaches possible:

- doing "wide loads", populating *multiple vector registers* from contiguous data at the same address
- doing "scatter-gather", populating vector constituents to/from *multiple addresses*

ARM and/or m68k have always done the former - the "move multiple" opcode on these platforms (`[v]ldm` on ARM, `movem` on m68k) allows specifying a mask which enumerates the registers to be populated from (consecutive) data at the given address.

Intel's x86 in all its history has never had this, except for `PUSHA` / `POPA` in 32bit which would unconditionally / nonmaskably save/restore the general-purpose registers to/from the stack, and that instruction was retired for 64bit mode.

Intel, with AVX, instead created the ability to simultaneously load *from multiple addresses*, i.e. do "scatter-gather".

So yes, the x86 replacement for something on ARM like:

```
VLDM.64 r0, {d1, d3, d5, d7}    ; load odd-numbered vector regs from mem @r0
```

would be a sequence:

```
VMOVAPD YMM1, [ RAX ]
VMOVAPD YMM3, [ RAX + 32 ]
VMOVAPD YMM5, [ RAX + 64 ]
VMOVAPD YMM7, [ RAX + 96 ]
```

On the other hand, the ARM equivalent (see [ARM docs, "indirect addressing"](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0350a/BABJJGIE.html)) of an x86 `VGATHER` instruction like:

```
VGATHERDD YMM0, [ RAX + YMM1 ]   ; YMM1[0..8] has 32bit offsets on RAX
```

requires a multiple loads to single elements of a vector register with a "combine" at the end - or, sub-register loads; it'd turn into a sequence:

```
VLD1.32 {d0}, [r0]                    ; r0..r3 have the [32bit] addresses
VLD1.32 {d1}, [r1]
VLD1.32 {d2}, [r2]
VLD1.32 {d3}, [r3]
VTBL d0, { d0 - d3 }, d4         ; d4 is [ 0, .., 7, ..., 15, ..., 31, ... ]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, those instructions are great for writing many vector processing routines.  Unfortunately for me, I was looking into something a bit different.  Some folks want to make [some of] the addition 16 vector registers "preserved", while others want them to be "scratch" like the current 16.  I was looking into a schere whereby a 32/64-bit [bitmask or count] value immediately before the function label tells which registers the callee modifies and possibly also have the caller place a similar value in r11 before it calls.  Then the number of saves/restores is always only what is needed.

Comment: This can be done in a couple ways, but the scheme is more strange looking than I'd like given the x86-64 instruction set.  I'll look for a better way for a while, but at this point it looks likely that we'll have to settle for extending the existing/conventional approach to the additional 16 registers.  These extra 16 vector registers should be designated "scratch", but unfortunately there is pressure from people who don't understand all the issues to make some or all of them preserved.  That looks good on the surface, but more careful, detailed analysis shows this is unwise.  Thanks.